# Is it possible to prioritise a tablespace for caching in RAM with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

We have a large postgres database (over 100GB) running off a server with 32Gb of RAM.

Some of the database we care much more about the performance of than other parts, so our idea is to put those tables in a separate tablespace, that can be optimised for being cached in RAM.

Is it possible to get postgres to prioritise caching one tablespace in RAM over another?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  Generally, the cache algorithms are smart enough to keep the most used tables and indexes cached.